# Let rankI be the rank relative to the insertion order for σ ∈ S9 . If rankI(σ) =9×8n+23, which value will assume σ(7)?

Tags: combinatorics, decision-trees

> Let $\mathrm{rank}_I$  be the rank relative to the insertion order for $\sigma \in  S_9$ . If $\mathrm{rank}_I(\sigma) = 9 \times 8n+23$, for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, which value will assume $\sigma(7)$ ?

Each tree's node of  the form $a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5a_6a_7$ has $8$ children and these children have $9$ children by themselves. Starting at one of these nodes, I can visit the children of the first child of the node I chose and then the children of the subsequent one and finally after visiting $5$ children of the third one, the next child will be the permutation that satisfies the above condition. By this method, $\sigma(7)$  seems to be equal to $8$. Should I rely on this method?